# playframework2 template, why the simple string is ok while the parameter with string get compile error

Tags: scala, templates, playframework-2.0

If my code is:

```
@(param: String)

@main("hello world") {
@slides("sssdfdes")
<div class="list-group">
</div>
```

}

It works, @main is my another template.
But if I want to do:

```
@(param: String)

@main(@param) {
@slides("sssdfdes")
<div class="list-group">
</div>
```

}

the compile get me error:

```
[info] Set current project to slickplay (in build file:/C:/testprojects/slickpla
y/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\testprojects\slickplay\target\scala-2.10\c
lasses...
[error] C:\testprojects\slickplay\app\views\shopmain.scala.html:6: illegal start
 of simple expression
[error] @main(@param) {
[error]       ^
[error] C:\testprojects\slickplay\app\views\shopmain.scala.html:15: ')' expected
 but '}' found.
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 08/04/2014 8:24:11 PM
```

How to passing variable string in scala template in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `@main(param)` instead of `@main(@param)`

Answer (score 1):

It is because u are using '*@*' multiple times in a single row,

```
Just use @main(param) instead of @main(@param)
```

answer is given by @serejja above